# Conditional Render vs TabNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render, tabnavigator

Case is that I have three screens, that display results fetched from an API and allows the user to dispatch actions on those results. Those actions trigger (should) results in the other two screens. In other words, if the user is on any screen and performs some action, the other two screens should update.

For instance, Screens A, B and C. I can do one of the two following approaches:

**- Conditional Render:**

```
class MainScreen extends Component {
    state: Object;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { currentActiveScreen: 1 }
    }

    componentWillMount()
    {
        this.retrieveResultForScreenA();
        this.retrieveResultForScreenB();
        this.retrieveResultForScreenC();
    }

    retrieveResultForScreenA()
    {
        // get results from API
    }

    retrieveResultForScreenB()
    {
        // get results from API
    }

    retrieveResultForScreenC()
    {
        // get results from API
    }

    ChangeScreen(screen_number)
    {
        this.setState({currentActiveScreen: screen_number});
    }

    render() 
    {
        if(this.state.currentActiveScreen === 1)
        {
            // render screen A results
            // along with a tab bar to switch screens:

            <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 1) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenA</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 2) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenB</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 3) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenC</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        }

        if(this.state.currentActiveScreen === 2)
        {
            // render screen B results
            // along with a tab bar to switch screens:

            <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 1) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenA</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 2) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenB</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 3) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenC</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        }

        if(this.state.currentActiveScreen === 3)
        {
            // render screen C results
            // along with a tab bar to switch screens:

            <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 1) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenA</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 2) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenA</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.ChangeScreen.bind(this, 3) }}>
                    <Text>ScreenA</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>       
        }
    } 
}
```

**- TabNavigator With Three Screens:**

```
class ScreenA extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({ title: 'ScreenA' });

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount()
    {
        this.retrieveResultForScreenA();
    }

    retrieveResultForScreenA()
    {
        // get results from API
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // render screen A results
        );
    }
}

class ScreenB extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({ title: 'ScreenB' });

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount()
    {
        this.retrieveResultForScreenB();
    }

    retrieveResultForScreenA()
    {
        // get results from API
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // render screen B results
        );
    }
}

class ScreenC extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({ title: 'ScreenC' });

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount()
    {
        this.retrieveResultForScreenC();
    }

    retrieveResultForScreenA()
    {
        // get results from API
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // render screen C results
        );
    }
}

const MainScreen = TabNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: MyScreenA },
  ScreenB: { screen: MyScreenB },
  ScreenC: { screen: MyScreenC },
});
```

Problem with the first approach is that:

- if user switches screens, application will fetch and use the network even if the user did not dispatch any action on any screen

Problem with the second approach is that:

- other tabs will not update on any action dispatched (tabNavigator renders once for all screens, and that is it)

How can I combine both approaches and have clean code, with up to date screens?

Comment: "if user switches screens, application will fetch and use the network even if the user did not dispatch any action on any screen";  If the only fetch is on the parent component's `componentWillMount`, then this is not true....

Comment: TabNavigator in react-navigation has a [`lazy`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig) prop

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here so I thought maybe it could help. lazy prop makes the Tabs render when they are switched. So if you pass to TabA to TabB TabB will be rendered that time.

Comment: No.  `ComponentWillMount` is called only once, when the component is rendered for the first time by it's parent.  `ComponentWillUpdate` is the hook which is called on every setState.

Comment: @bennygenel exactly what you just said is what I am trying to achieve, I want to use a TabNavigator and rerender everything when tabs are switched. However, lazy props did not do that

Comment: But the problem is that your actions happen on main component and the switch happens between tab screens. so main component will be rendered only once unless its state or props changes.

Comment: @bennygenel if I fetch in `componentWillUpdate`, I get an infinite loop. Since setState() is inside it (everytime I fetch new result, i put them in state).  And it happens on both lazy : true and false

Comment: ^ cc @gravityplanx

Comment: So don't do that?  If you only want to fetch once, do so in `ComponentWillMount`.

Comment: @gravityplanx I want to fetch in all tabs, every time the user do something on one tab

Comment: Then those user actions should trigger a handler function which dispatches whatever fetch calls you need.  You shouldn't be packaging them inside of lifecycle hooks unless you want them to trigger on those lifecycle hooks.  User input != lifecycle.

Comment: @gravityplanx I see. Can you show an example of a handler function please? I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the discussion happening in the comments;

It seems like what you really want is a handler function that can trigger updates on specific user actions.  This fits, somewhat, into your "Conditional Render" design pattern.  I'll give an example, but extremely simplified;

```
class MainScreen extends Component {
    state: Object;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { currentActiveScreen: 1 }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.handleFetchRequest();
    }

    getTabSelection() {
        return (
            //some JSX with links that controls `state.currentActiveScreen`
        );
    }

    handleFetchRequest() {
        this.retrieveResultForScreenA();
        this.retrieveResultForScreenB();
        this.retrieveResultForScreenC();
    }

    getCurrentScreen() {
        if(this.state.currentActiveScreen === 1) {
            return <ScreenA onFetchRequest={this.handleFetchRequest}/>;
        }
        if(this.state.currentActiveScreen === 2) {
            return <ScreenB onFetchRequest={this.handleFetchRequest}/>;
        }
        if(this.state.currentActiveScreen === 3) {
            return <ScreenC onFetchRequest={this.handleFetchRequest}/>;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.getTabSelection()}
            {this.getCurrentScreen()}
        </div>;
    }
}

class ScreenA extends Component {
    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.props.onFetchRequest}/>;
    }
}
```

So in the above example, the component will call `handleFetchRequest` once when the component first mounts, and then will call additionally when the user clicks the button rendered within `ScreenA`.  Any other updates or re-renders of the components will not cause a re-fetch.

You can continue to extend this to other user actions that should trigger a refetch, such as `onFocus` or `onBlur` of input fields.